# OneVsRestClassifier Hyperparameter Tuning for every base estimator

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, cross-validation, hyperparameters, multiclass-classification

I am working on a multiclass problem with six different classes and I am using OneVsRestClassifier.
I have then performed hyperparameter tuning with `GridSearchCV` and obtained the optimized classifier with `clf.best_estimator_`.

As far as I understand, this returns one set of the hyperparameters for the aggregated model/every base estimator.
Is there a way to perform hyperparameter tuning separately for each base estimator?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just reverse the order of the search and the multiclass wrapper:

```py
one_class_clf = GridSearchCV(base_classifier, params, ...)
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(one_class_clf)
```

Fitting `clf` generates the one-vs-rest problems, and for each of those fits a copy of the grid-searched `base_classifier`.